# Does C create a seperate frame in Stack for a function which has an array as an argument

Tags: c, function

How does C represent the function which has an array as an argument in Memory? Does it create a separate frame for it in the **stacke**? If so, how does it fill in the passed array "by reference"? Can you explain the logic behind this process?

Comment: There is no "pass by reference" in C, an array decays into a pointer when passed to a function. Take a look to the [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrparam.html)

Comment: Even if it convers it into pointer, does it create a separate frame in memory? And does it fill that pointer in that frame? And how about the passed Array?

Comment: The pointer is passed as part of the stack frame for the function, just like any other argument.

Comment: So, no new stack frame for the new created function but, the same main() frame when it has pointers as arguments?

Comment: @Downvoter That depends on your platform's ABI and the number of arguments. On e.g. 64-bit Linux, the first six args are passed in registers, no stack involved.